# Submitting a component form with different components

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I have two components - Catalog and Catalog.Inventory. When the detail page `/Detail/{id}` is invoked, the catalog components looks for components that is configured to show on that page and does a `Html.Action()`.

The question is, what would be a clean way to submit the form(s) with the data going to the appropriate controller.

I could contain each form in its own tab and have a Save button on each of the tabs but multiple save buttons it will just frustrate the user.

Catalog/View.cshtml

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()..)
{ 
   <button type="submit">Save</button>

   var tabCollection = _tabManager.GetTabsFor("thispage");

   <div class="nav-tabs">
       <div class="tab">General Info</div>
       @foreach(var tab in tabCollection)
       { <div class="tab">@tab.TabTitle</div> }
   </div>   
   <div class="content">
   {
       <div class="content"> /* Catalog Fields */</div>
       @foreach(var tab in tabCollection)
       {
          // the View of this action will have its own <form>
          @Html.Action(tab.Action, tab.Controller, new{id = Model.Id});
       }
   }
}
```